# Should fix or false positive - Fortify Path Manipulation Error

Tags: c#, fortify

I have following web api code which does not take any input for filename or path from user and works internally but got an path manipulation error in  fortify scan. Should this be fixed or mark as false positive as there will be no intervention through user inputs?

public IEnumerable Load()
{
string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContractFiles"];
List fileList = new List();
IEnumerable files = this.GetXmlFilesFromPath(path);
foreach (string file in files)
{
//Path Manipulation
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(file);
}
}

private IEnumerable GetXmlFilesFromPath(string path)
{
//Path Manipulation
return Directory.GetFiles(path).Where(p => p.ToLower().EndsWith(".xml")).ToArray();
}

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Métoule Does this code need to be fixed or no need? In my opinion, this code does not take any user input or not writing any content to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it doesn't make the analyzer message go away, I would amend it to:

```
return Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml");
```

Comment: What about the first error it's asking for loading file. I agree your point to use pattern. And, even if message does not go away, can it be false positive?

Comment: You need to add more details to your question.. Put some screenshots

Comment: I will if can, if you specify any thing what exactly.